# galaxy s2 wifi problem after updating to ice cream sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2

hi guys i have samsung galaxy s2 and it was working very well before upgrade to ice cream sandwich i didnt face any trouble in upgrading and it upgrade well

but i faced a problem with wifi connection after upgrading ...
and the only solution i had is to reset the router...the problem that i search for this problem in the internet and i found this problem happened to others but i didnt found solution to that 
problem details:
it connect normally and tell me that the device connected to the network but there is no internet and when i try to use the wifi to transfer data it says wifi not connected but when you go to the wifi settings it says connected!!

i dont reach access and i dont get IP address when i go to advanced settings said IP unavailable when i reset the router it take an IP the router has no problem on the other devices
so i need a permanent solution does not include factory reset if possible

Comment: What is the problem, can please you explain? Like what happens when you are trying to connect to WiFi?

Comment: it connect normally and tell me that the device connected to the network but there is no internet and when i try to use the wifi to transfer data it says wifi not connected but when you go to the wifi settings it says connected!!

Comment: i dont reach access and i dont get IP address when i go to advanced settings said IP unavailable when i reset the router it take an IP the router has no problem on the other devices

Comment: Please edit as many details as possible into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is kind of a caching ip address error. If you have been connected before the phone does not try to obtain an IP address because the one it got before is still assigned by the network.

What usually works for me is to connect to another network. I have plenty of open networks around where I live. This will make the phone to obtain a new ip address for the new network and delete the old one.

Now simply connect to your network again and the phone will try to obtain a new ip address and will actually communicate with the dhcp.

Worked for my galaxy s2. Hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't own a Galaxy S2. However, I can tell you some steps that you can try. So let me know how it helps. It will be like trial and error. Please tell me what happens when you try this, I will accordingly update the answer.

So first things first, I think it is a problem related to getting IP address. So first, try changing IP address manually. Here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM1oysibgU0) that will guide you in doing this. (Not my video)

Try it and see how it helps.

Comment: ok thanks for your help but i tried this way and it didnt work but i searched in the internet and i found way says : goto settings>applications>all>software update ..clear data and restart the device and it works without troubles until now and i dont know if this way!! work

Comment: Ok. That's cool! I would request you to add your solution as an answer, that may help anyone who has a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.  This fixed it for me too.  Goto: `Settings --> Applications --> All --> Software Update`. Clear all the data and restart the device, this should work without trouble.